# Is JavaScript's .setSelectionRange() incompatible with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, html-input

This question revamps a [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/b077dx/javascripts_setselectionrange_incompatible_with/) on r/reactjs.

I have a controlled `input` of which I can programmatically change the value. I would like to use [`.setSelectionRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) in order to maintain the caret position within the input.

Except this doesn't work: **each re-render automatically sets the selection range to the end of the input by default**.

The problem is illustrated in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jj253yvq9w), where the author of the original question fixed the problem with a 10ms `setTimeout()` delay.

How do I achieve this without using `setTimeout()` or [`getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate), which is not compatible with Hooks?

Comment: FYI that the link to the sandbox is dead now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem as I see it is that `.setSelectionRange()` is being used in-line in the template, and should be wrapped in a `useEffect()`.

I would also pull the selection handler out, just to be a bit tidier (as per `handleDomainChange()` and `handleSubmit()`).

**useEffect for selection update**

```js
const[selection, setSelection] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  if (!selection) return;  // prevent running on start
  const {start, end} = selection;
  inputEl.current.focus();
  inputEl.current.setSelectionRange(start, end);
}, [selection])

const handleSelection = (e) => {
  const start = inputEl.current.selectionStart;
  const end = inputEl.current.selectionEnd;

  ... // other code within selection handler as per original

  // inputEl.current.focus();
  // // the line below doesn't work!
  // // inputEl.current.setSelectionRange(start + e.native.length, end + e.native.length)

  // //this one does, but is not good practice..
  // setTimeout(
  //   () =>
  //     inputEl.current.setSelectionRange(
  //       start + e.native.length,
  //       end + e.native.length
  //     ),
  //   10
  // );
  setSelection({start: start + e.native.length, end: end + e.native.length});
}
```

**template change to call handleSelection()**

```html
<Picker
  set="emojione"
  onSelect={event => {
    handleSelection(event)
  }}
/>
```

---

**Original code for reference**

```html
<Picker
  set="emojione"
  onSelect={e => {
    const start = inputEl.current.selectionStart;
    const end = inputEl.current.selectionEnd;
    //const result = domainString.substring(0, start) + e.native + domainString.substring(end, domainString.length)

    setDomainString(
      prevString =>
        prevString.substring(0, start) +
        e.native +
        prevString.substring(end, prevString.length)
    );

    setDomainsArray(
      domainEndings.map(
        ending =>
          domainString.substring(0, start) +
          e.native +
          domainString.substring(end, domainString.length) +
          ending
      )
    );

    inputEl.current.focus();
    // the line below doesn't work!
    // inputEl.current.setSelectionRange(start + e.native.length, end + e.native.length)

    //this one does, but is not good practice..
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        inputEl.current.setSelectionRange(
          start + e.native.length,
          end + e.native.length
        ),
      10
    );
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Nice, this solution makes more sense than having to use setSelectionRange in a setTimeout! Neat